# MySQL: How do I select two fields from table, and total of amount columns in two related tables?

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have three tables:

`Project`
`PurchaseA`
`PurchaseB`

Schema of Project:

```
id | user_id | title | description | create_date
```

Schema of PurchaseA:

```
id | project_id | amount | create_date
```

Schema of PurchaseB:

```
id | project_id | amount | create_date
```

`Project` has a bunch of unique rows detailing different projects. Each of these projects has many rows in both `PurchaseA` and `PurchaseB`. What I want to do is select all of the rows from `Project` with the fields `id` and `title`, but also the SUM of both the total of the related records in `PurchaseA` and the total of the related records in `PurchaseB`.

I can get it working sort of independently of each other, but when I have two joins, the numbers end up being massively inflated.

**Desired Result**

```
21732 Test Project A          84274.48
21747 Test Project B          18237.47
34714 Test Project C         183747.18
```

Where the column with the FLOATS is the sum of the related rows from `PurchaseA` and `PurchaseB`.

**Edit**

Here is my current SQL:

```
select 
    projects.id,
    projects.title,
    COALESCE(SUM(PurchaseA.amount), 0) as pledgetotal,
    COALESCE(SUM(PurchaseB.amount), 0) as purchasetotal
from
    projects
        left join
    PurchaseA ON (PurchaseA.project_id = projects.id)
        left join
    PurchaseB ON (PurchaseB.project_id = projects.id)
        left join

WHERE
    projects.title IS NOT NULL

    projects.end_date < NOW()
group by projects.id
```

**Test Data**

```
Projects:

id          title           description         create_date

623         Test Project A  This is a test A    2013-01-01
624         Test Project B  This is a test B    2013-01-02


PurchaseA

id          project_id      amount              create_date
1           623             100                 2013-01-02
2           623             125                 2013-01-02
3           624             200                 2013-01-03
4           623             150                 2013-01-03
5           624             50                  2013-01-04

PurchaseB

id          project_id      amount              create_date
1           623             110                 2013-01-02
2           624             105                 2013-01-02
3           623             215                 2013-01-03
4           623             100                 2013-01-03
5           624             150                 2013-01-04
```

So as you can see, each project has multiple rows in each related table. I want to get the sums from each table, then add those together.

Comment: Please post the SQL query you have so far

Comment: Can you post some sample data for each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe part of your problem is from the one-to-many relationship that exists between the `projects` and the `purchase.` tables. My suggestion would be to move the `sum()` to subqueries:

```
select 
    p.id,
    p.title,
    a.pledgetotal,
    b.purchasetotal
from projects p
left join
(
  select project_id, sum(amount) pledgetotal
  from PurchaseA
  group by project_id
) a
  ON (a.project_id = p.id)
left join
( 
  select project_id, sum(amount) purchasetotal
  from PurchaseB
  group by project_id
) b
  ON (B.project_id = p.id)
WHERE p.title IS NOT NULL;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09b01/6)

Comment: Works like a champ *thumbs up*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (not tested):

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, (pa.amount+pb.amount)  AS TotalPurchase FROM Project a
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT project_id, SUM(amount) AS amount FROM PurchaseA GROUP BY project_id ) pa
    ON pa.project_id = a.id
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT project_id, SUM(amount) AS amount FROM PurchaseB GROUP BY project_id ) pb
    ON pb.project_id = a.id
```

Comment: That returns NULL for most of the rows

Comment: this is the same as the answer flagged as correct, I just didn't have any idea of what you wanted in the `WHERE` clause. ;)

Comment: when i ran yours, all the fields were NULL - his were not?